# Unexpected SQL select exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception, select, actionlistener

actually I am newbie in java and SQL so maybe it will be dumb question sorry in advance. I am not used to write in some forums or smth. I prefer looking for to have answer immediately. Anyway now i am helpless I couldnt find it anywhere because I didnt know what to look for so i found this way as better.

So I have few problems I will divide them for better understand.

```
    if (stmt.execute(
                        "SELECT * FROM products where ID=" + removeName)) {
                    rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    if (!rs.next()) {
                       m = "ID not found.";
                        return m;
                   }
```

1.(SOLVED THANK YOU MARC B)In this code if I put into my field some text (not number) it will throw me this exception : SQLException: Unknown column 'blabla' in 'where clause' even though in my database is ID set as String and everywhere it is String.

2.(SOLVED my brain turned on for a while)I am doing my project to school and it is warehouse system and there is a cashier who is making orders. He is adding products into order list and then when order list is finished (cashier is not going to add there anymore - click order) it should remove that products from warehouse database. I would like to ask (again sorry i tryied to solve it with some actionListeners or arrays or something but as I told I am not so skilled) if there is any posibility to save data (Id, quantity) which are in order list (to some variable or somewhere) for later removing it from database? I though it would be good save it to array but every button click add it should increase index of array but i have no idea how to increase i (maybe that actionListeners) or maybe some better way. Thank you for everything.

```
while (rs.next()) {
                String entry = rs.getString(1);
                String entry1 = rs.getString(2);
                int entry2 = rs.getInt(3);
//check if there are enough products in warehouse
                if(quantity>entry2){
                   m+="There are not enough product(s) with ID: "+entry1+"\nin the warehouse.\n";
                   return m;
                }
//add to the order list
                m += "Product name: " + entry + "\n"
                        + "ID: " + entry1 + "\n"
                            + "Quantity: " + quantity + "\n" + "\n";
            }
```

EDIT CODE by adding into while loop after entry1 and entry2 were initialized:

```
a.add(new Product(entry1, entry2));
```

While it is declared as ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Product> a=new ArrayList<>();
```

And Class Product looks like this :

```
    public class Product {
public String name, ID;
public int quantity;

public Product(String ID, int quantity){
this.ID=ID;
this.quantity=quantity;}


public Product(String name, String ID, int quantity){
this.name=name;
this.ID=ID;
this.quantity=quantity;}

public String getID(){
      return ID;}


public int getQuantity(){
      return quantity;}


}
```

Hope editing will help.
Maybe it is too huge question and maybe it should be divided somehow but as I told i am not using forums to ask only to look for so for every answer I will be gratefull(also for critics about my post). Again sorry and thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Basic SQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM sometable
WHERE somefield=somevalue, otherfield='othervalue'
```

`somevalue` in the above query is not quoted, so it will be parsed/interpreted as a reference to a FIELD in a table. By comparison, `'othervalue'`, with the single-quotes (`'`) is interpereted as a STRING.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be interpreted as a reference to a field because my program is looking for the product in database with ID the same as is value inputed in the Field. Anyway thank you if that what i said is wrong tell me.

Comment: so? if you insert a string into an sql query and the string isn't quoted, the DB engine is going to interpret it as a field name. `where product_type=toy` will make the DB engine look for a field named "toy" in your table. but if you do `where product_type='toy'`  the db engine scan the table and see if the word "toy" shows up in the product_type field of any records in the table.